# onmouseover trouble with android

Tags: javascript, onclick

i have a div in my website that onmouseover makes a button appear, the trouble is on android when they tap on that div to make the button appear it makes it appear and does the onclick action for that button (on Iphone it does not behave this way) are there any work arounds?

Comment: Solution: don't use mouse events for mobile sites.

Comment: this is for a website ppl access from their phones browser also what is the alternative?

Comment: don't use onmouseover on mobile mobiles don't have mice.

Comment: Look for touch libraries or do some research on implementing the correct touch events, this might be a better question for stack UX

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz If you really need to, use [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) for mobile. Triggering hover state with JavaScript is already a bad enough design idea though.